# How to remove checkbox selection from all views in checkbox selection model in EXT grid

Tags: extjs, ext4

I have a Ext grid with checkbox selection Model. The grid contains multiple pages of 50 records each. I have a 'Clear Selections' button to deselect all the selected rows in the selection model.
The code for this is :

```
 handler: function(){
         this.selectionModel.deselectAll();
         this.selectedReordsArray.clear();

         },
        scope: this
```

The problem is, when I select some records in the first page and move to second page and select some records there as well. Now if I click 'Clear Selections' button it deselects the rows on that page i.e. second page , but when I go back to page 1 , the rows there are still selected.
Is there any way to remove checkbox selections from all the pages.

Thanks,

PS : I am using Ext JS 4.1.3

Comment: Yes this is because As per doc `deselectAll()` method "Deselects all records in the view."

Comment: Yes this is because As per doc `deselectAll()` method "Deselects all records in the view.". Well What you can do is u can reload the store. let me check if any other trick is there to solve.

Comment: I have tried doing store.loadPage(1) , but the rows are still checked.

Comment: I found the solution . Apparently what i needed to do was to  do this:
    ' grid.store.clearData();
    grid.store.removeAll();
   grid.store.loadPage(1);'

Comment: You can share this. Did'nt get much time on this.  `grid.store.load()` is one idea which I got. well pls share

Answer (score 0):

Add "pruneRemoved: false" for your selmodel. Then try adding deselectAll() method for your gridstore. This will clear selected records from all pages.